# How come a Class can be registered as a Spring Bean in XML configuration but not with Annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In the spring documentation [Standard and Custom Events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/context-introduction.html#context-functionality-events) it shows registering a class as a bean

```
<bean id="blockedListNotifier" class="example.BlockedListNotifier">
   <property name="notificationAddress" value="blockedlist@example.org"/>
</bean>
```

But trying the same thing as a annotation gives a compile error of

> '@Bean' not applicable to type

```
@Bean
public class BlockedListNotifier implements ApplicationListener<BlockedListEvent> {

    private String notificationAddress;

    public void setNotificationAddress(String notificationAddress) {
        this.notificationAddress = notificationAddress;
    }

    public void onApplicationEvent(BlockedListEvent event) {
        // notify appropriate parties via notificationAddress...
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is? It is okay to use @Component instead?

Comment: _It is okay to use @Component instead?_ That's what you should be using, or the specialized types like `@Service` or `@Controller`, as appropriate. `@Bean` annotates bean factory methods in `@Configuration` annotated classes.

Answer (score 0):

The XML Tag is called `Bean` and the annotation is called `@Bean`. So why arent they homogeneous? Yes, I understand your confusion.

```
<beans>
  <bean id="blockedListNotifier" class="example.BlockedListNotifier">
    <property name="notificationAddress" value="blockedlist@example.org"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

is more the equivalent of:

```
@Configuration
public class Beans {
  @Bean // <-- only allowed on methods
  BlockedListNotifier blockedListNotifier(){
    return new BlockedListNotifier();
  }
}
```

Because neither of them need to add annotations to the class.